# Returning MONTH and YEAR in the same column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Currently I have a query that returns MONTH, YEAR, COUNT(*).

The charting program I am using needs the date field to be in one cell. I am making a month to month chart, therefore I will need each month (ex Jan 2011) to be returned as 2011-01-31 (preferably the last day of every month.

To cover any holes I may have left: I have a whole slew of dates people registered with my site. I need to simply return a two column query:

| YEAR-MONTH | COUNT(*) |

Thank you everyone in advance for your help! Please let me know if I need to clarify any sections.

Comment: Well, what have you attempted?

Comment: I already built the View that returns MONTH YEAR COUNT*. I was considering using cast or convert to try to combine the two MNTH/YR columns into one.

Comment: And my super roundabout solution to this would be a table where I convert every day of each timestamp to 01, then run the query for DATE, COUNT*. But this is just because I am thinking super out of the box because I am grasping at straws.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you that looks helpful. Giving it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine them using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(myDateColumn, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(myDateColumn, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The [date_format() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is probably what you're looking for.

```
select date_format(your_column_name, '%Y-%m')
from your_table;
```